# backboneJS application runs fine in NodeJs but not in any other server?

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

I was trying to load a json file in Collection of BackboneJS. While trying to run this through nodeJS server, it works fine. But once put in a server environment like XAMPP or even in a remote server it does not work? Any link would be a nice help. ( For reference my code is at github : **https://github.com/saumya/backboneJS-basics** )

thanks

Comment: it seems that while running from XAMPP server, the application only works on safari but no other browsers !

Comment: Haven't looked at your code, but working only in Safari sounds to me like you're trying to load the JSON from the file system, not over HTTP from the server.

Comment: I would go with something along the lines of same origin policy

Comment: hey @fencliff thats perfect guess as I am loading json. But i tried loading it from server XAMPP on windows.

Comment: thanks guys for the helping hand. Well there is not much of a code to share, but then I am putting part of the collection class here `var SlidesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: SlideModel, 
  url: "assets/data/slides.json", ` and in view file I am instantiating it with a fetch call `this.slidesCollection=new SlidesCollection();
    this.slidesCollection.on("reset",function(event){
     this.onCollectionUpdatedWithData();
    },this);
    this.slidesCollection.fetch(); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey thanks for the helping hand.
Probably I did not understand the situation, so the question is not correct as I see now.

The modified question is:

1. I have a frontend Application running on NodeJS server at some port.
2. I am trying to load JSON from another server running on another server.

The answer of @Floby is the way I solved it. [Its the CORS thing](http://enable-cors.org/) on the server which provides the JSON. It took me sometime to understand what is happening.